# C# code example to view and edit google spreadsheet on google data viewer

Tags: google-drive-api

How to view and edit google spreadsheet on google data viewer using C# Asp.Net Code?

Answer (score 1):

In order to view/modify spreadsheets data programatically, you should use the [Spreadsheets API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I gone through the help you given. But Is it possible to open google spreadsheet on google viewer using C# Asp.Net Code and Edit the same on google viewer?? If you provide Some Code Example which help me. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Here is the new version of the Spreadsheets API. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api